# How can I improve the performance of this PHP/MySQL code?

Tags: php, mysql, performance

The following is a part of a bigger PHP script which adds or disables users from a MySQL database using a **CSV file** and a **client id** field as input.

There are two tables involved, **users** and **users_clients**. The later keeps the relationship between users and clients as an user can belong to multiple clients.

This is the structure of the tables

**users** structure (it has more fields)

```
id        | int(11) (primary key)
user      | varchar(100)
pass      | varchar(100)
category  | int(11)
date      | timestamp
name      | varchar(100)
email     | varchar(255)
```

**users** indexes

```
SEARCH    | user        | FULLTEXT
SEARCH    | name        | FULLTEXT
SEARCH    | email       | FULLTEXT
```

**users_clients** structure

```
id_user   | int(11)
id_client | int(11)
status    | enum('active','inactive')
```

This is the basic flow of the script for adding each user from the CSV file:

1. Check if the user exists for that client.

   ```
   SELECT 
       LOWER(user)
   FROM
       users u
       INNER JOIN users_clients uc ON u.id = uc.id_user
   WHERE
       u.user = '$user'
       and uc.id_client = $id_client
   ```
2. If it doesn't exist, add it to the database.

   ```
   INSERT INTO 
       users ($fields,id_client)
   VALUES 
       ($values,'$id_operation')
   ```
3. Get the id of the inserted user. 
   I know I could use something like **mysql_insert_id** here, but what about the race conditions?.

   ```
   SELECT
       u.id as id
   FROM
       users u
   WHERE
       u.user = '$user'
       and u.id_client = '$id_operation'
   ```
4. Associate the user with the corresponding client.

   ```
   INSERT INTO
       users_clients (id_user, id_client) 
   VALUES
       ('$id_user','$id_client')
   ```

There are currently 400.000 users in the table. The script takes 10+ minutes to process a CVS with 500 users.

How would you improve this so that it is faster?

Thanks in advance.

PD: If you want to see the complete function, it's available at [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/k8dNzVjB).

Comment: you should create a store procedure that does all the work.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You should not have a race condition with mysql_insert_id. Just give it the connection you used for the insert.

Comment: by the way, you can also speed up this thing with mySQL config improvements (google for "mysql primer"). i dont know your dimensions, but in case your are doing this 10hrs per day, there might be a significant performance boost

Comment: @ceejayoz: updated question to include table structure and indexes. Users has a FULLTEXT index that includes user, name and email fields.

Comment: @Panique: looks interesting, I will check it out. Performance is not critical for this script as it's used just a few times per day, but it can't hurt to save some time and learn to write better code :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table (id,a,b,c) VALUES (5454,1,2,3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE table SET foo WHERE id=xyz;
```

1. Set indexes in the DB
2. use mysqli instead of mysql
3. collect all the stuff you want to insert and do it with a prepared statement / stored procedure like here [How to insert an array into a single MySQL Prepared statement w/ PHP and PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629022/how-to-insert-an-array-into-a-single-mysql-prepared-statement-w-php-and-pdo)
4. don't do 500 SELECTs, simple get the entire database and work through it via a foreach/while loop, checking for the stuff you need
5. use a construct like above

**Important:** For the above statement the column **id** should have an unique index !!!

Comment: I don't think that mysqli is any faster than mysql, except for the use of prepared statements, which is obvious from point 3.

Comment: @Mike I'm not sure about that, but the official php docs say "use mysqli because it's faster" or something like that. well, we simply don't know that ;) ... maybe somebody can bring up some benchmarks here ?

Comment: Fortunately, somebody already has http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171400/which-is-fastest-in-php-mysql-or-mysqli

Comment: #4 - Don't use a `foreach` every time, get your list of usernames into an array then test with [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) - more efficient

Comment: @Panique:
#1 Just updated the question with table structure and indexes. Should I add additional indexes?

Answer (score 2):

Wrap INSERTs into transaction and don't worry, `mysql_insert_id()` is completely safe unless you switch to another database connection.

It is also possible to wrap all your queries to a transaction in result of massive speed improvement.