# Connect to SQL Server through PDO using SQL Server Driver

Tags: php, sql-server, windows, pdo

I am trying to connect to an existing SQL Server database using PDO with the [drivers provided by Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098).

I have seen examples using odbc, dblib, mssql, etc., however I believe the connection string with these drivers should use 'sqlsrv'?

Are there any good examples of how to properly do this? If I should be doing this via some other method please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Well that's the best part about PDOs is that it's pretty easy to access any database. Provided you have installed those drivers, you should be able to just do:

```
$db = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=YouAddress;Database=YourDatabase", "Username", "Password");
```

Comment: What drivers do I need to enable on the server? Enabling only the pdo_odbc will work?

Answer (score 12):

Mind you that in my experience and also of other ([PHP - Why is new SQLSRV driver slower than the old mssql driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825949/php-why-is-new-sqlsrv-driver-slower-than-the-old-mssql-driver)) that using PDO_SQLSRV is way slower than through PDO_ODBC.

If you want to use the faster PDO_ODBC you can use:

```
//use any of these or check exact MSSQL ODBC drivername in "ODBC Data Source Administrator"
$mssqldriver = '{SQL Server}'; 
$mssqldriver = '{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}';
$mssqldriver = '{ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server}';

$hostname='127.0.0.1';
$dbname='test';
$username='user';
$password='pw';
$dbDB = new PDO("odbc:Driver=$mssqldriver;Server=$hostname;Database=$dbname", $username, $password);
```

Comment: May you check my question related http://serverfault.com/questions/722670/s1090unixodbcdriver-managerinvalid-string-or-buffer-length

Comment: This didn't work for me with the curly braces. Works great as `$mssqldriver = 'ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server';`

Comment: on a new server the old sqlsrv driver would not connect. this saved me a BUNCH of time. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

This works for me, and in this case was a remote connection:
Note: The port was IMPORTANT for me

```
$dsn = "sqlsrv:Server=server.dyndns.biz,1433;Database=DBNAME";
$conn = new PDO($dsn, "root", "P4sw0rd");
$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Table";

foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Figured this out. Pretty simple:

```
 new PDO("sqlsrv:server=[sqlservername];Database=[sqlserverdbname]",  "[username]", "[password]");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
try
{

    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$server_name;Database=$db_name;ConnectionPooling=0", "", "");
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

}
catch(PDOException $e)
{

    $e->getMessage();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$database = "";
$port = "1433";
try {
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$servername,$port;Database=$database;ConnectionPooling=0", $username, $password,
        array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        )
    );
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo ("Error connecting to SQL Server: " . $e->getMessage());
}
```