# How to make SQL server 2012 work with php?

Tags: php, sql, xampp

How do I connect SQL server 2012 with php 5.6.3?

Like in mysql I use phpMyAdmin, how is it done in SQL server 2012?

Where do I have to save the database?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing changes much while using different database service.

You can use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012 to create and manage your database.

Databases are automatically saved to SSMS's ( SQL Server Management Studio ) default location. But they can be easily transferred to different location by copying .mdf and .ldf files.

While using php ( or any other language ), make sure to keep running SQL Server Service and use proper connection String to connect to database.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out! :)

Comment: For any query, feel free to ask.

Mark it as answered and close the question please.

Answer (score 1):

**Connecting to database**

If you are on windows, use [sqlsrv](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.installation.php) extension and do not forget install SQL Server Native Client 2012. sqlsrv supports also PDO - just use right [connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747554/connect-to-sql-server-through-pdo-using-sql-server-driver). On unix try to use mssql or odbc extension.

**phpMyAdmin alternatives**

*SSMS* (SQL Server Management Studio 2012) - tool that you can use but it is more for database administrators than developers.

*SSDT* (SQL Server Development Tool) - similar to SSMS but it is also capable to creating snapshots, comparing schemas, data-tier apps and much more. It is a part of Visual Studio or as standalone app.

**Administration**

SQL Server is a little bit more sofisticated database than MySQL. Database files are stored in Program Files by default (.mdf for database files, .ldf for transactions log). All administrator tasks, that you want to make as developer, could be done from SSMS (not from configuration file).