# How to fetch data using sqlsrv in php

Tags: php, sqlsrv

I'm trying to fetch data from database using sqlsrv in php. But it's showing me 0 count. Attaching my code too.

```
//check if form is submitted
if (isset($_POST['login'])) 
{
    $email = ($_REQUEST['email']);
    $password = ( $_REQUEST['password']);
    $result = "SELECT * FROM  Users WHERE email = '" . $email. "' and password = '" . md5($password) . "'";
    $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $result, array(), array( "Scrollable" => 'static' ));

    $row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows($query);
    echo $row_count;

    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query))
    {
        echo 'yes';
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: Please, tell me how to fetch data from databse using sqlsrv as i'm new to ms sql server.

Comment: Try with `PDO`, check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747554/connect-to-sql-server-through-pdo-using-sql-server-driver/36212561#36212561

Comment: Did you try to log the prepared query which is stored in `$result`, is it as supposed to be?

Comment: @Marek Skiba My connection is working fine, only problem is I'm not able to fetch data from databse.