# Cannot connect to SQL Server in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, database, sqlsrv

I trying to connect to a MSSQL Server with PHP. For that I am using the following script:

```
function mssqli_connect($server,$username,$password,$database){
    $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>$database, "UID"=>$username, "PWD"=>$password);
    return sqlsrv_connect($server,$connectionInfo);
}
```

I am running PHP 7.0.7 on a Windows Server with the IIS 7.5. Unfortunately it doesn't work and I have no idea why.

**What I've already tried**

I dumped the function, but it only returns `bool(false)`, which is not very helpful. I also tried to ping the server via cmd. This has succeeded. The credentials are also correct.

The extension `php_sqlsrv_7_nts.dll` is also requested in the `php.ini`, so it doesn't give me an error, that the function wasn't found.

Do I miss something, which is required?

Comment: Have you installed the driver?

Comment: Which driver? I only required the DLL.

Comment: These https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=20098 The PHP extension is not all you require, it only talks to these native drivers

Comment: Why not use PDO to [connect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747554/connect-to-sql-server-through-pdo-using-sql-server-driver) to sqlsrv? I find it to have a much friendlier API.

Comment: @RiggsFolly this programm will only outputs the DLL. Or what I have to do with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched again. Now what I found is an other driver software, which is a msi executable file, which installs the odbc driver on the machine.

https://www.microsoft.com/de-ch/download/details.aspx?id=36434

I installed that software and now it works without any problems.

Thanks for all your comments.