# sqlsrv not getting installed for php 7.4

Tags: php, docker, sqlsrv, pecl

I am trying to install sqlsrv drivers for php with Dockerfile, but it is not working, I am getting error that pecl sqlsrv requires php 8.1, current version 7.4. I cannot update php to 8.1 because there are other dependencies, is there any other way I can install sqlsrv for php 7.4. Here is the dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4-cli as php 

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y unzip libpq-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev gnupg2 zlib1g-dev libpng-dev libnss3-dev libatk1.0-0 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libcups2 libdrm2 libxkbcommon-x11-0 libxcomposite-dev libxdamage1 libxfixes-dev libxrandr2 libgbm-dev libpangocairo-1.0-0 libcairo2 libasound2
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql bcmath gd exif

RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install msodbcsql17 unixodbc-dev
# RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools
RUN pecl install sqlsrv
RUN pecl install pdo_sqlsrv
# RUN docker-php-ext-enable sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash - 
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN npm install

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

WORKDIR /var/www
COPY . .

ENV PORT=9000
ENTRYPOINT [ "Docker/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

Comment: I have already looked at other links for help, but nothing is working.

Comment: MS only provides sqlsrv for 8.1, but there are other ways to connect to sql server from 7.4. One option you could try is to use the ```pdo_dblib``` extension which provides a driver for FreeTDS to connect to sql server.

Comment: Use PDO, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747554/connect-to-sql-server-through-pdo-using-sql-server-driver.

Comment: Take a look at this link https://gist.github.com/leidison/6a935c9416151c9bad53694f20bfaf59#file-ubuntu20-04_php7-4_sqlsrv-sh

Comment: @fly2matrix  it is showing error E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu noble Release' does not have a Release file.

Comment: `pecl install sqlsrv-5.10.1 pdo_sqlsrv-5.10.1`

support for php 7.4 was removed in 5.11.0 

https://pecl.php.net/package/pdo_sqlsrv/5.11.0
https://pecl.php.net/package/pdo_sqlsrv/5.11.0