# MySQL performance again MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am upgrading older code from mysql_ to mysqli and i found myself writing a replacement for the common :

```
mysql_result();
```

What i wrote was :

```
function mysqli_result($res, $row, $field=0) { 
$res->data_seek($row); 
$datarow = $res->fetch_array(); 
return $datarow[$field]; 
}
```

But im curious, is there anyway to precisely benchmark the two without hindering any performance speed and if so what would be the best way about it ?

Comment: Mysql_result were the worst worst way of getting data from mysql. there is no point in dragging it into brave new world of mysqi, nor in any benchmarks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which is fastest in PHP- MySQL or MySQLi?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171400/which-is-fastest-in-php-mysql-or-mysqli)

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO it is not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future.

With that said, concerns of benchmarks and performance are irrelevant. Furthermore, following the 80/20 rule, optimization should be focused on your queries and DB structure well before code.

Nonetheless, I did run my own simple benchmarks years ago when making the switch. I found `mysqli` to be more performant than `mysql`. Moreso when using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

As noted by **Your Common Sense**, performance is also heavily dependent on how you write your code. Be sure you understand the difference in the libraries and which methods to use.

Comment: Thats fair enough, i guess its just my own curiosity which is interested in the benchmarking of db queries !

Comment: @Pogrindis benchmarking this function has nothing to do with benchmarking db queries.

Comment: of course, but the query times of the same tables using both methods would be interesting to know, out of mild curiosity i guess.

Comment: I queried the same table with the same `INSERT` and `SELECT` queries, `mysqli` was more performant.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO, that question is 5 years old. Clearly the `mysqli` extension has established its supremacy since then.

Comment: Thanks Jason for this.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO, with `mysql` deprecated, I'd say `mysqli` won out. Furthermore, the *i* does stand for *improved* :)

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO, you brought up the *2008 model*. I'm just saying that 5 years later the top answer of that question my no longer be right (noting `mysql` is faster than `mysqli`).

Answer (score 1):

MySQLi is an 'Improved' way of interfacing with the same database, it has many memory and speed enhancements in addition to support for;

- Prepared Statemments
- Multiple Statements
- Transactions

MySQLi can also be written in both OOP style and procedural style.

If you scroll down to the bottom of the page on [MySQLi Overview](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php) offers it will you'll see a comparison table.

If you're interested in benchmarks, I came across a blog which you might want to take a look at [Blog - ioMeWeekly](http://iomeweekly.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/benchmark-php-mysql-vs-php-mysqli.html)

Comment: Like many other "blog posts" this one can actually tell you nothing neither on the "speed difference" nor on the necessity of such a benchmark.

Comment: old mysql ext is okay with 
    Prepared Statemments,
    Multiple Statements and 
    Transactions. I can't believe so many people are dragging this rumor along

Comment: It provides the scripts enabling the reader to test themselves. It then answers the question 'Is it faster for me, in my environment?'.

Comment: Sadly, you don't get the point. This test is essentially useless by intention and wrong by implementation. In any environment.

Comment: Using PDO extension it supports prepared statements etc however the standard MySQL extension does not. Referencing: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: PDO can emulate prepared statements. Mysql ext can do it as well. Referencing: own experience.