# Which is the most secure and correct solution to display only one value from a single row using SELECT in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My question is which solution do you think is best to use when wanting to retrieve only one value from a MySQL DB row.

For example, let's say we have the following:

-table `"users"` with three rows `"username","password" and "status"` AND three users "user1","user2" and "user3".

If I want to select only the status of one user (let's say user1) and set it to a variable, I will use:

```
$user_status = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT status FROM users WHERE username='user1'"),0);
```

I searched the net and I see that people use different methods of retrieving this type of info, such as setting LIMIT 1 inside the select code or by retrieving the whole users list and then sort the one that matches their needs.

I am wondering if my solution is the best and secure way (including security from SQL inject, keeping in mind that no `$_GET` method is used in the php code).

Maybe use both `LIMIT 1` and the method I used above (for the code to require less resources and time to execute)?

Comment: What is the cocern with sql injection here? If you do not use user input then that should not be possible. Though I wonder how you want to do that, since somehow you have to specify which user you are currently testing...

Comment: Or you could use PDO and stored procedures....and do not use the mysql extension, go for mysqli or PDO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a database point of view the safest way is to have a **unique key** in the table you are selection from and retrieve the row via this key. In your example you could have a userID column that holds a unique ID for each user. If you query `WHERE userID='...'` the database guarantees you that there can only be one result row.

**Edit**: "Public opinion" suggested that I add two things.

1. Thou shall not use mysql_*! Why not use [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)? You should not have to worry about [its performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171400/which-is-fastest-in-php-mysql-or-mysqli).
2. There is no reason to use `LIMIT 1` if you are using proper database design - no reason at all. Its a bit like writing code that says `Enter car; Make sure you have entered exactly one car;`. `LIMIT` can be used in other cases like retrieving the first 10 results of many.

Comment: You should also mention to move away from the deprecated `mysql_*` and adopt `mysqli`, or preferably `pdo`

Comment: I believe it's some kind of login system, so using ID is not an option here.

Comment: I just posted a basic example, so I was hoping for a general answer, not a specific one. That being said:
@SebastianH - I know how to make sure to be only one field with the mentioned value, the question is how to retrieve it more clean and fast.
Also, I am used with mysql, but I know mysqli is the one I will want to use. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: if you are concerned with performance (which you should not except for cases where this is really crucial) then - again from a database point of view - a key is important. I guess I dont have to lecture on data retrieval from a column with no key at all -> full table scan.
@Андрей Почекуев In that case it would be crucial to have a unique username which amounts to the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the PDO methods if you want any security, regular mysql calls have been fased out for a while

Use mysqli (https://www.php.net/mysqli), but check here http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Your query though would be SELECT `status` FROM `users` WHERE `username`='user1' LIMIT 1

Answer (score 0):

First one - you don't use `mysql_` methods anymore - they're deprecated and natively unsafe.
Second - you use PDO interface, like this

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT `status` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ?");
    $stmt->execute(array($_GET['username']));
    $status = $stmt->fetchColumn();

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'PDO Error : ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Using `prepare` - `execute` chain is safe with PDO - it is automatically sanitized, so you don't have to worry about mysql injections. At `prepare` part you create a query with parameter, and in `execute` part you execute your prepared query with parameter equaling `$_GET` and store the result. Any error you encounter along the way is being caught in the `catch (PDOException $e)` block and can be handled appropriately.