# MySQLi query too slow in loop

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, codeigniter-3

Okk here's my code snippet

```
foreach ($res->result() as $row)
        {
            $query = "SELECT count(*) AS count FROM
                      (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT TASKS.task_ID) AS count
                      FROM
                  TASKS JOIN TRANSLATOR_LANGUAGES
                  JOIN PROJECT_USERS JOIN TRANSLATED_TASKS JOIN PROJECTS
                      ON
                  (TASKS.task_ID = TRANSLATED_TASKS.task_ID AND
                  TASKS.project_ID = PROJECT_USERS.project_ID AND
                  PROJECTS.project_ID = TASKS.project_ID AND
                  TRANSLATED_TASKS.language_code = TRANSLATOR_LANGUAGES.language_code AND
                  PROJECT_USERS.translator_ID = TRANSLATOR_LANGUAGES.translator_ID AND
                  PROJECT_USERS.language_code = TRANSLATOR_LANGUAGES.language_code)
                  WHERE
                  ? = TRANSLATOR_LANGUAGES.language_code AND
                  ? = TRANSLATOR_LANGUAGES.translator_ID AND
                  ? = PROJECT_USERS.project_ID AND
                                  TASKS.archived < ?
                  GROUP BY TASKS.task_ID, TRANSLATOR_LANGUAGES.language_code, PROJECTS.vote_threshold
                  HAVING " . $this->getHavingClause($filter) . ") STATS_PHP"; 

            $res2 = $this->db->query($query, array($row->language_code,
                                       $translator_ID,
                                   $project_ID,
                                   $archived))->result_array();
```

When this same code I am executing in php5.2 it executes within seconds but it takes more than 500 seconds to complete in php7 (MySQLi).

I am using codeigniter 3.1.0 for development, and I am trying to move php5.2 base webApp to php7.

Can somebody Help?

Comment: Have you profiled your code to see if the performance difference is in PHP code versus the SQL query? Have you tested the SQL query directly in the MySQL client (that is, not using PHP)? Are you using a different MySQL version as well, as you upgrade to PHP 7? Have you run an [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) report or query [PROFILING](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-profile.html)? And compared the EXPLAIN and PROFILING reports on both old and new versions of MySQL?

Comment: When asking for help with SQL query performance optimization, you should always include the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>` for each table in your query. Include the version of MySQL (`SELECT @@version`). Include the `EXPLAIN` report of the query.

Comment: At the top of your code example, it shows you are running this query in a loop. Is the loop based on the result of an earlier query? How many times does this loop? Is it possible it's looping over a larger result, resulting in 100 times more iterations than your old app? How do you monitor this?

Comment: Make sure that each JOIN clause has a corresponding ON clause, this will help in reducing the cross joins you will get.  You don't have ON clauses for -TRANSLATOR_LANGUAGES, PROJECT_USERS and TRANSLATED_TASKS